# Combine Code Arduino GSM Shield and Adafruit GPS Shield

Tags: arduino-uno, shields, gsm

I have a problem to combine both code for Arduino GSM Shield and Adafruit Ultime GPS Shield. I already change my code to the basic one like examples. I think i found the problem. The problem is when i want to do get request to the url/web.

**Here is the link to the Adafruit Ultimate GPS Shield.**
[Adafruit Library](https://github.com/adafruit/Adafruit-GPS-Library)
[Adafruit Ultimate GPS Shield Info](https://learn.adafruit.com/adafruit-ultimate-gps-logger-shield)

My code base on example of Arduino GSM Library (GSM Web Client) and Adafruit GPS Library (Parsing)

**This is the code that make my code not working. If i put the code i do not receive any data at serial.**

[image: Blank Data at serial]

```
 // if you get a connection, report back via serial:
 if (client.connect(server, port))
 {
    Serial.println("connected");
   // Make a HTTP request:
   client.print("GET ");
   client.print(path);
   client.println(" HTTP/1.1");
   client.print("Host: ");
   client.println(server);
   client.println("Connection: close");
   client.println();
 } 
 else
 {
  // if you didn't get a connection to the server:
  Serial.println("connection failed");
 }
```

**This is the basic code that working so far**

[image: Working Code]

```
// ********************************************
//   GPS Library
// ********************************************
#include <Adafruit_GPS.h>
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


// ********************************************
//   GSM Library
// ********************************************
#include <GSM.h>


// ********************************************
//   Sim Card Pin Number if available
// ********************************************
#define PINNUMBER ""


// ********************************************
//   Set Up APN data for GPRS Connection
// ********************************************
#define GPRS_APN       "Maxis" // replace your GPRS APN
#define GPRS_LOGIN     "maxis"    // replace with your GPRS login
#define GPRS_PASSWORD  "wap" // replace with your GPRS password


// ********************************************
//   Initialize GSM Library
// ********************************************
GSMClient client;
GPRS gprs;
GSM gsmAccess; 

// ********************************************
//   Setup Arduino to browse URL/web through GPRS
//   The code below will setup path like:
//   http://arella.com.my/urltomysql.php?firstname=Muhammad&lastname=Faiz
//   When Arduino browse the web, it will submit firstname:Muhammad
//   and lastname:Faiz into database. I want to store GPS data into database       later
// ********************************************
char server[] = "arella.com.my";
char path[] = "/urltomysql.php?firstname=Muhammad&lastname=Faiz";
int port = 80; // port 80 is the default for HTTP


// ********************************************
//  Set Adafruit GPS to use software serial on pin 
//  D9 & D10 on Arduino. Use Jumper Wire from D7,D8 to D9,D10
// ********************************************
SoftwareSerial mySerial(10, 9);
Adafruit_GPS GPS(&mySerial);


// Set GPSECHO to 'false' to turn off echoing the GPS data to the Serial console
// Set to 'true' if you want to debug and listen to the raw GPS sentences. 
#define GPSECHO  false

// this keeps track of whether we're using the interrupt
// off by default!
boolean usingInterrupt = false;
void useInterrupt(boolean); // Func prototype keeps Arduino 0023 happy


//***********************************************
// convert NMEA GPS Format to Google Map Format
//***********************************************
int degLatInt, degLongInt;
float minLatFloat, minLongFloat, googleMapsLat, googleMapsLong;
char* lat_str = new char[10];
char* long_str = new char[10];
char degLatString[5], degLongString[5];


void setup()  
{ 
   Serial.begin(115200);
   gsmAccess.begin(PINNUMBER);
   gprs.attachGPRS(GPRS_APN, GPRS_LOGIN, GPRS_PASSWORD);

   boolean notConnected = true;
   while(notConnected)
   {
      if((gsmAccess.begin(PINNUMBER)==GSM_READY) &
         (gprs.attachGPRS(GPRS_APN, GPRS_LOGIN, GPRS_PASSWORD)==GPRS_READY))
         notConnected = false;
      else
      {
         Serial.println("Not connected");
         delay(1000);
      }
   }
   // If i enable the code below, my code not working.
   /* if (client.connect(server, port))
      {
      Serial.println("connected");
      // Make a HTTP request:
      client.print("GET ");
      client.print(path);
      client.println(" HTTP/1.1");
      client.print("Host: ");
      client.println(server);
      client.println("Connection: close");
      client.println();
  } */


 //***********************************************
 // Setup Adafruit GPS Shield
 //***********************************************
 // connect at 115200 so we can read the GPS fast enough and echo without  dropping chars
 // also spit it out

 Serial.println("Adafruit GPS library basic test!");

 // 9600 NMEA is the default baud rate for Adafruit MTK GPS's- some use 4800
 GPS.begin(9600);

 // uncomment this line to turn on RMC (recommended minimum) and GGA (fix     data) including altitude
 GPS.sendCommand(PMTK_SET_NMEA_OUTPUT_RMCGGA);
 // uncomment this line to turn on only the "minimum recommended" data
 //GPS.sendCommand(PMTK_SET_NMEA_OUTPUT_RMCONLY);
 // For parsing data, we don't suggest using anything but either RMC only or RMC+GGA since
 // the parser doesn't care about other sentences at this time

 // Set the update rate
 GPS.sendCommand(PMTK_SET_NMEA_UPDATE_1HZ);   // 1 Hz update rate
 // For the parsing code to work nicely and have time to sort thru the data, and
 // print it out we don't suggest using anything higher than 1 Hz

 // Request updates on antenna status, comment out to keep quiet
 GPS.sendCommand(PGCMD_ANTENNA);

 // the nice thing about this code is you can have a timer0 interrupt go off
 // every 1 millisecond, and read data from the GPS for you. that makes the
 // loop code a heck of a lot easier!
 useInterrupt(true);

   delay(1000);
}

// Interrupt is called once a millisecond, looks for any new GPS data, and stores it
SIGNAL(TIMER0_COMPA_vect) {
   char c = GPS.read();
   // if you want to debug, this is a good time to do it!
   #ifdef UDR0
   if (GPSECHO)
   if (c) UDR0 = c;  
   // writing direct to UDR0 is much much faster than Serial.print 
   // but only one character can be written at a time. 
   #endif
}

void useInterrupt(boolean v) {
   if (v) 
   {
      // Timer0 is already used for millis() - we'll just interrupt somewhere
      // in the middle and call the "Compare A" function above
      OCR0A = 0xAF;
      TIMSK0 |= _BV(OCIE0A);
      usingInterrupt = true;
   } else 
   {
      // do not call the interrupt function COMPA anymore
      TIMSK0 &= ~_BV(OCIE0A);
      usingInterrupt = false;
   }
}

uint32_t timer = millis();

void loop()                     // run over and over again
{
   // if a sentence is received, we can check the checksum, parse it...
   if (GPS.newNMEAreceived()) {
   // a tricky thing here is if we print the NMEA sentence, or data
   // we end up not listening and catching other sentences! 
   // so be very wary if using OUTPUT_ALLDATA and trytng to print out data
   //Serial.println(GPS.lastNMEA());   // this also sets the newNMEAreceived()  flag to false

   if (!GPS.parse(GPS.lastNMEA()))   // this also sets the newNMEAreceived() flag  to false
      return;  // we can fail to parse a sentence in which case we should just wait for another
   }

   // if millis() or timer wraps around, we'll just reset it
   if (timer > millis())  timer = millis();
   // approximately every 2 seconds or so, print out the current stats
   if (millis() - timer > 5000) { 
      timer = millis(); // reset the timer

      Serial.print("\nTime: ");
      Serial.print(GPS.hour+8, DEC); Serial.print(':');
      Serial.print(GPS.minute, DEC); Serial.print(':');
      Serial.print(GPS.seconds, DEC); Serial.print('.');
      Serial.println(GPS.milliseconds);
      Serial.print("Date: ");
      Serial.print(GPS.day, DEC); Serial.print('/');
      Serial.print(GPS.month, DEC); Serial.print("/20");
      Serial.println(GPS.year, DEC);
      Serial.print("Fix: "); Serial.print((int)GPS.fix);
      Serial.print(" quality: "); Serial.println((int)GPS.fixquality); 
      if (GPS.fix) {  
         /////////// Latitude /////////////
         // Convert NMEA Latitude to String
         dtostrf(GPS.latitude, 7, 4, lat_str); //convert GPS.latitude from float to String. 7 - means 8 characters long ; 4 - means 4 decimal point 

         // Get Degree substring from latitude String
        strncpy(degLatString, lat_str, 1); // Get Degree from Full Latitude String. Example 311.7799 - Get 3

        // Get Minutes substring from latitude String
        char* minLatString = lat_str + 1; // Move pointer up 1 position. Example 311.7799 will move to 11.7799

        // Convert Deg String to int
        degLatInt = atoi(degLatString);

        // COnvert Min String to float
        minLatFloat = atof(minLatString);

        //Convert NMEA latitude to Google Maps latitude
        googleMapsLat = degLatInt + (minLatFloat / 60); 
        Serial.print("Google Map Latitude: ");
        Serial.println(googleMapsLat, 4);

        //////////// Longitude /////////////
        // Convert NMEA Longitude to String
        dtostrf(GPS.longitude, 8, 4, long_str); //convert GPS.latitude from float to String. 8 - means 9 characters long ; 4 - means 4 decimal point 

        // Get Degree substring from latitude String
        strncpy(degLongString, long_str, 3); // Get Degree from Full Latitude String. Example 10141.91699 - Get 141

        // Get Minutes substring from latitude String
        char* minLongString = long_str + 3; // Move pointer up 3 position. Example 10141.9169 will move to 41.7799

        // Convert Deg String to int
        degLongInt = atoi(degLongString);

        // COnvert Min String to float
        minLongFloat = atof(minLongString);

        //Convert NMEA latitude to Google Maps latitude
        googleMapsLong = degLongInt + (minLongFloat / 60); 
        Serial.print("Google Map Longitude: ");
        Serial.println(googleMapsLong, 4);

        Serial.print("Speed (KM): "); Serial.println(GPS.speed * 1.85);
      }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm working on the same project (with the same hardware) and I have an identical problem.
Seems like an HTTP request blows up your serial monitor, but is not true in my view. 
In fact, if you use the TinyGPS++ library will not have this problem anymore.
Take as reference the GsmWebClient example, you can add a few lines of code.

This is all you need for parse with tinyGPS:

```
#include <AltSoftSerial.h>

#include <TinyGPS++.h>

TinyGPSPlus gps;

AltSoftSerial ss;

//Add this to your sketch, in loop() or setup()

ss.begin(9600);

while (ss.available() > 0)

    if (gps.encode(ss.read())) {
        gps.location.lat(); //return latitude as a double
        gps.location.lng(); //return longitude as a double
}
```

Comment: Does that code fix the issue?

Comment: Thanks penguin for editing!
This is not a real fix for the error, it's a bypass.. I think the problem is given by AdafruiGPS lib, and everything is solved using TinyGPS. This code is all you need for get the coordinates with the new library.